# Datastage Director issue while scheduling

Tags: datastage

I am trying to schedule datastage job using datastage director client 11.7.

But facing issue:

Error adding to schedule:sh:/usr/bin/at:permission denied

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the datastage engine user is able to schedule `cron` and `at` jobs. `cron` is used to schedule recurring jobs wheras `at` is used to schedule "one-shots". In some environments, these services are not activated by default anymore and must be enabled.

Comment: how can i check if datastage engine is able to schecule crob jobs

Comment: Login to your system with your engine user (default would be `dsadm`) and try using `crontab -e`. Depending on your operating system there might be different ways to allow using crontab and at.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `dsadm` is unable to perform scheduling.
DataStage uses Linux internal scheduling utility such as `cron/at` to schedule the jobs, check whether `dsadm` has the privilege to do it.